# Language X tags on library questions, when language Y wraps a library written in language X?

Tags: discussion, tags, code-languages

If you look at the [top unanswered questions for the [C++] tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++?sort=unanswered&pageSize=50), you realize that most (if not all) of them are not really questions *about* C++ but rather about how to do something in a third-party library, which happens to have a C++ front end.

**Is it OK to tag these questions with C++?** I often find myself looking at the C++ tag for good language-related questions, but they are often buried below the sea of library specific, language agnostic questions.

Comment: There's a feature request somewhere about "tag hierarchies".

Comment: Related [question about creating a "c#-language" tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62669) on Meta.SE.

Comment: Related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298019/389812

Comment: @Cerbrus: not that's not an exact duplicate, please ask before you make assumptions. Where a C/C++ or Java package is wrapped for (say) Python or R, users often have issues with triggering crashes, coredumps, exceptions, memory leaks, multithreading, mystery stacktraces. These are quite clearly "problems that are directly connected to coding in language X". Since we're trying to use the wrapped code in language Y, they're also "directly connected to coding in language Y".

Comment: Look, most of the time the use-case is an urgent *"I downloaded package P wrapped for language Y, I'm following the doc but it gives all these unintelligible errors in language X, is this fixable, is it due to my client code? or due to the package itself just broken/bug-happy/unuseable and should I just abandon using it?"* And by the way the answer to that urgent question is quite often "Yes, it's unuseable", which is very important information, even if it's one word long. (Have you ever tried to use jython, for example?) And the rest of the time, often the answer is "Upgrade to version V"

Comment: @smci: This question is about ___5___ years old, and I closed it over a year ago. If the closure were wrong, it'd have been reverted already. Just vote to re-open it. I don't see why you need to ping me about this, especially with a presumptuous line like _"please ask before you make assumptions"_.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

If a question is about a specific language, it should have the associated language tag.
Whether or not it involves some 3rd-party library should be irrelevant.

In fact, the language tag is usually the most important tag on a question since it is how most people will find the question.

---

It's not a coincidence that many of the top unanswered questions are about niche/obscure libraries. It's because they are niche and obscure that nobody has been able to answer them yet.