# Questions tagged [flutter] should automatically use Dart for syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting, code-languages

Often times [flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter) questions don't really apply to Dart specifically, so adding the [dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dart) tag isn't really ideal. Instead, using `<!-- language: dart -->` before code blocks is currently necessary.

Answer (score 6):

For other people who don't know what [Flutter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flutter_(software)) and [Dart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dart_(programming_language)) are:

> Flutter is Google’s mobile app SDK for crafting (...) native interfaces on iOS and Android (...) — [flutter.io](https://flutter.io/)

Furthermore:

> Apps are written in [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), (...) — [technical overview](https://flutter.io/technical-overview/)

As such, I am in favor of associating [flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter) with Dart syntax highlighting, just like [dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dart) is.

---

Side note: it is [perfectly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250876) [fine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298019) to tag Flutter questions with [dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dart).